# C++11 features compatibility with different versions of GCC

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc, g++

Following, my previous question about  [How to safely deploy an application built with an upgraded compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41445003/6475652), there is still a doubt for me about the C++11 features compatibility. Using devtoolset-2, the application that will be built with gcc 4.8.2 but linked with  libstdc++.so.6.0.13 will have full C++11 features supported or only the common set with libstdc++6.0.19 ?

I am not really sure to understand this point actually.

Comment: Forget about C++11. You can only expect that C++ code compiled by a given compiler can only be linked with that compiler's corresponding library. It is not guaranteed that you can compile your code with a given version of the compiler, link it with the library from an older version, and expect anything to work.

Comment: Ok so how to use the devtoolset-2 then ? It become useless in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be mixing libstdc++ like that, so it's a moot point. You should redistribute the libstdc++ that comes with devtoolset-2 and link against that specifically. Otherwise the compiler and standard library will be at odds with each other, and even *they* won't know the answer to your question!

Then, simply look up a list of what C++11 features are supported in GCC 4.8.2.

Comment: Actually, i understand that there is no mixing between libstdc++ using devtoolset-2 that is provided by RedHat ( but i am using the centos version ) to upgrade the compiler and still using the system libstdc++. So the app is built and run with the same version of libstdc++ (6.0.13). GCC 4.8 is supposed to be backward compatible with libstdc++ 6.0.13 but i ask about the C++11 features support.

Comment: @Scab: I don't see how libstdc++ can be unconditionally backwards-compatible. Where would `std::thread` support come from? Move semantics in containers? All the other C++11 features that live in the standard library? Maybe the GCC devs have managed to make it so that a newer compiler can always use an older standard library implementation, but then I guess the answer is "you just don't know what you're going to get". Hence I'd avoid it.

Comment: According to this https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html , i understand that some versions of GCC are compatible with older libdstc++ version, especially if there is only a change in the minor number version ( like 6.0.13 and 6.0.19 ). If there is any doubt about that, then why Red Hat has released their devtoolset collections ? So if i need C++11 full support on centos 6.7 what can i do ? Use gcc 4.8.3  and it's libstdc++ 6.0.19 version ? and so deploy also all the dependancies with the right versions of libc, libgcc_s when deploying the app on centos 6.7 ?

Comment: @Scab: Again I'm no expert so take this with a pinch of salt, but that's what I do (except for libc) and it means I know for sure I have all of C++11 out of the box. I'm hopeful that our customers will migrate from el6 within a few release cycles anyway so I haven't given it much more thought tbh.