# nm devtoolset's .so files gives File format not recognized

Tags: gcc, centos7, devtoolset

I am just curious why `nm` complains:

> File format not recognized

if I do:

```
$ nm /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.so
nm: /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.so: File format not recognized
```

However, same command can be executed successfully against the stock one `/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a shared library. It is a ld script used at compile-time and not run-time
`cat /opt/rh/devtoolset-8/root/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/libstdc++.so`

> /* GNU ld script
>     Use the shared library, but some functions are
>   only in
>     the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
>   OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf64-x86-64)
>  INPUT ( /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
>   -lstdc++_nonshared )

For *OUTPUT_FORMAT* and *INPUT* explanation : see https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.32/ld/LD-Index.html#LD-Index

Comment: Thanks!  A non related question (hope you don't mind) -- what's in libstdc++_noshared.a?  Complement to `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6` to provide the new features covered by GCC 8?

Comment: @HCSF. It does not mind. I think you will find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15602073/7462275.

Comment: Never thought of the answer would come from that post.  Thanks!